# @media CSS in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, media-queries

So, I'm trying to use @media in CSS on my rails project.
I have a text which needs to be displayed only on mobile Heres the code

a.html.erb

```
    <div class="A__b--c-d"> 
    <%= link_to .......
     ....
    </div>
```

b.scss

```
div.A__b--c-d {
    display: none;
}




@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 900px){
  .A__b--c-d{
     display: inline-block;
   }
 }
```

I cannot seem to get the text displayed on mobile.

Heres what ive tried so far.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 Pasted this in Chrome inspect element

 All the names are right
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the .div and just select the max-width in your media query.

```
.A__b--c-d {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
  .A__b--c-d{
     display: inline-block;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your media query. Try this

```
 .A__b--c-d {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
  .A__b--c-d{
     display: inline-block;
   }
 }
```